# "Installed" checkbox in Xcode Storyboard Attributes Inspector

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

In Xcode Interface Builder there is an option `Installed` in the Attributes Inspector.

I am unsure of it's meaning. Does it mean that the element will be present in any size class?

[image: installed checkbox]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is for adding that specific view to the corresponding size class. If the installed is checked it will be added to the view hierarchy of that size class, else it won't be added. You can check more about this option in [Enable And Disable Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnableAndDisableViews.html).

Comment: I am actually confused about the first "Installed" statement. It is not connected to any size class.

Comment: @krompir2: You can see a "+" before that "installed" item (All other have "x"). It means you can add a new size class there and it will be automatically in installed mode.

Comment: ok, the plus is for adding new size classes. To the right, there is a checkbox. Does this checkbox mean that the element is present in all size classes?

Comment: @krompir2: That means, it is going to be added to the new size class you are adding there using the plus. If it is unchecked, then the view won't be added to the size class you are adding there using the plus.

Comment: aaa I see. Thank you kind sir!