# Uninstalled IB Property in storyboard vs. superview property

Tags: swift, uiview, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

I am having trouble understanding the nuances of setting a view to *not installed* in the storyboard.
[image]

As far as I understood, this property is the equivalent of adding/removing the view from its superview. So the `myView.superview` property.

**But** it seems that constraints, that the view itself has (not from the superview, so e.g. width/height) are lost, when the view is set to *not installed* in the IB, but referenced as an IBOutlet and added to the view hierarchy later. 
**On the other hand** leaving it *installed* in IB and removing then adding it again preserves the width/height constraints.

Thus *installed* and `.superview`  cannot be equivalent. What is the deal here?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975427/installed-option-in-attributes-inspector

Comment: Disabling installed will cause to behave as if you didn't add that UI element at all, **meaning** it will not be compiled in your view hierarchy